# Need to add image in the Instantiated object

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, game-physics, 2d-games

I am following a tutorial on youtube.This is a swipe menu tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njfc_QYKdio&t=229s
I tried and understood what he have done.

```
public class SecMenuScene : MonoBehaviour {
    [Range(1, 50)]
    [Header("Controllers")]
    public int panCount;
    [Range(0, 500)]
    public int panOffset;
    [Range(0,20)]
    public int snapSpeed;
    [Range(0,6)]
    public int scaleOffset;
    [Range(0,20)]
    public int scaleSpeed;
    [Header ("Other object")]
    public GameObject panPrefab;
    public ScrollRect scrollRect;


    private GameObject[] instPans;
    private Vector2[] panPos,panScale;


    private RectTransform contentRect;
    private Vector2 contentVector;

    public int selectedPanID;
    public bool isScroling;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


        contentRect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        instPans = new GameObject[panCount];
        panPos = new Vector2[panCount];
        panScale = new Vector2[panCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < panCount; i++)
        {

            instPans[i] = Instantiate(panPrefab, transform, false) ;


            if (i == 0) continue;
            instPans[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector2(instPans[i - 1].transform.localPosition.x + panPrefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x + panOffset,
                instPans[i].transform.localPosition.y);
            panPos[i] = -instPans[i].transform.localPosition;

        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        if(contentRect.anchoredPosition.x>= panPos[0].x && !isScroling || contentRect.anchoredPosition.x <= panPos[panPos.Length - 1].x  && !isScroling)
        {
            scrollRect.inertia = false;
        }
        float nearestpos = float.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < panCount; i++)
        {
            float distance =Mathf.Abs( contentRect.anchoredPosition.x - panPos[i].x);
            if (distance < nearestpos)
            {
                nearestpos = distance;
                selectedPanID = i;
            }
            float scale = Mathf.Clamp(1 / (distance / panOffset) * scaleOffset, 0.5f, 1);
            panScale[i].x = Mathf.SmoothStep(instPans[i].transform.localScale.x+0.3f, scale, scaleSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            panScale[i].y = Mathf.SmoothStep(instPans[i].transform.localScale.y+0.3f, scale, scaleSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            instPans[i].transform.localScale = panScale[i];
        }
        float scrolVelocity = Mathf.Abs(scrollRect.velocity.x);
        if (scrolVelocity < 400 && !isScroling) scrollRect.inertia = false;

        if (isScroling || scrolVelocity>400) return;
        contentVector.x = Mathf.SmoothStep(contentRect.anchoredPosition.x, panPos[selectedPanID].x, snapSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        contentRect.anchoredPosition = contentVector;
    }
    public void Scrolling(bool Scroll)
    {
        isScroling = Scroll;
        if (Scroll) scrollRect.inertia = true;
    }
}
```

But the problem is now I am not able to change the image of prefab obj. I tried taking instantiate obj and change sprite using SpriteRenderer. But unable to find the solution. If anyone can help or advise what I should read to make it working.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can hold a reference to your desired sprite like other public variables that are declared:

```
 [Header ("Other object")]
public GameObject panPrefab;
public ScrollRect scrollRect;
[SerializeField]
private Sprite sprite; // or Sprite[] sprites if you need more than one
```

then you can add an Image component to your prefab in Editor and set its size and position the way you like.

```
for (int i = 0; i < panCount; i++)
    {

        instPans[i] = Instantiate(panPrefab, transform, false) ;
        // you can get the reference to your Image component and set its sprite
        Image im = instPans[i].GetComponent<Image>();
        im.sprite = sprite; // or im.sprite = sprites[i] if you are using multiple sprites

        if (i == 0) continue;
        instPans[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector2(instPans[i - 1].transform.localPosition.x + panPrefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x + panOffset,
            instPans[i].transform.localPosition.y);
        panPos[i] = -instPans[i].transform.localPosition;

    }
```

Comment: Mahdad baghani bro, Thanks a lot. Thank you for helping.:). Just 1 more thing I am a newbie and i have just copy the code from the video. Because of this now I know the use of Range,Header,Because of you now Serialization. But i am unable to understand the script. can you comment on the code what this line do. So that i can understand the code. If you have time. If not then no issue you have already helped me a lot. Thank you

Comment: Thank you Mahdad Baghani for helping. With your help I am able to make my 3rd game.I have mention you name in description hope you don't mind.
https://lifeisjourney.itch.io/snowman

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though these are UI objects which have an Image component in place of a SpriteRenderer. You instead need to get this component to change the image source.

ex.

```
instPans[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = mySprite;
```

Comment: rye Moss. Bro ,Thanks a lot. Thank you for helping.:). It really worked now I have a swipe menu screen :)